# Rails parsing through data on the backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Photo and Product models.

In create action of product controller I want to find all unassociated photos and connect them to current product. I am trying to find all photos that belong to current user which product id is nil.

Then for each photo I would set product id to @product.id

What should I do?

```
def create
  @product = current_user.products.create(params[:product])
    if @product.save
      render "show", notice: "Product created!"

      # code here 

    else
      render "new", error: "Error submitting product"
    end
  end

   def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token(cookies[:auth_token]) 
  end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "photos", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "product_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
end

create_table "products", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "user_id"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should use **build** instead of **create** to build a instance of product, otherwise the following line `if @product.save` will be meaningless. So the code should like this:

```
def create
  @product = current_user.products.build(params[:product]) # using build to construct the instance
  if @product.save
    render "show", notice: "Product created!"

    # Update un-related Photos
    Photo.where(:product_id => nil).update_all(:product_id => @product.id) 

  else
   render "new", error: "Error submitting product"
  end
end
```

Comment: it was actually Photo.where(:product_id => nil, :user_id => current_user).update_all(:product_id => @product.id)   but GREAT JOB THANKS SAVED MY LIFE

Answer (score 1):

For organisation, you should do this in `Product` model:

```
class Product

  before_save :set_unassigned_photos

  def set_unassigned_photos
    self.photos = user.photos.unassigned
  end
```

and in `Photo` model:

```
class Photo

  scope :unassigned, where(product_id: nil)
```

This way you follow thin controller fat model "suggestion". Your controller would remain untouched.